# cross chain token

Tags: solidity, tokens

I see a lot of projects that have their token on multiple chains. I was wondering how they do it?
I guess they build a contract for each blockchain but how the liquidity works? how can people move their assets from one blockchain to another (I am talking about Ethereum based blockchains like bsc/polygon/Ethereum)?

Comment: Same question for me. And if I can add more questions, how they can keep the same price ? For example matic is on the (BSC/Polygon/Avalanche/Solana), and I realised they have a different contract

Comment: @RaphaëlEtang-Salé "how they can keep the same price?" They don't always keep the same price, but then traders come and exploit the arbitrage opportunity, so they go back to the same price again.

Answer (score 0):

Within a centralizer process. Wrapped tokens such as WBTC you need to send some BTC to an centralized project that can mint WBTC in the desirable chain for you. And even among dexes in the same chain someone needs to make some arbitrage to make the price paired.